# Authenticator addAccount causing crash

Tags: java, android, authentication

I'm attempting to write an Authenticator component and I keep getting a runtime exception that I can't solve. All I've implemented is the addAccount() method. I attempt to add an account via Android's Settings -> Accounts -> Add Account. I select the Account Type which appears successfully in the list. The Authenticator is started and calls addAccount(). It stops short of successfully starting the Authentication Activity though and throws this exception:

```
01-28 17:38:57.599     886-1466/? W/Binder﹕ Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.android.server.accounts.AccountManagerService$Session.onResult(AccountManagerService.java:2203)
            at android.accounts.IAccountAuthenticatorResponse$Stub.onTransact(IAccountAuthenticatorResponse.java:59)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

The implementation of the Authenticator's addAccount():

```
final Bundle bundle = new 
final Intent intent = new Intent(context, AuthenticatorActivity.class);

intent.putExtra(AuthenticatorActivity.ARG_ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType);
intent.putExtra(AuthenticatorActivity.ARG_AUTH_TYPE, authTokenType);
intent.putExtra(AuthenticatorActivity.ARG_IS_ADDING_NEW_ACCOUNT, true);

intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, response);

bundle.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, intent);

return bundle;
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you happen to find an answer yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the same  problem, but my solution may or may not apply to you.

I am using [AndroidAnnotations](http://androidannotations.org/), and my `AuthenticatorActivity` class was annotated to be an `@EActivity`. Therefore, I should have constructed the intent using `AuthenticatorActivity_.class` (notice the underscore!), which is the class generated for me by AndroidAnnotations. My original class would have had a lot of null variables.

In the future, I will have to be careful to keep this in mind, as there are no errors or warnings at build time.

I hope this helps you, too.

By the way, I have found a related [AndroidAnnotations Issue](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/issues/1017) which discusses other scenarios where we have to explcitly use the generated class name. There is also a discussion of how this might be addressed, but the Issue is still open.